# Grafana mysql multiple value variable

Tags: grafana

I am having two variables in grafana for data source MySql, one is Site where i have enabled multi value option and second is Topic. Now i want that if we select multiple values in Site variable, Topic variables should reflect those changes but that's not working.

Table i am using is this -
[image]

Although normal query in mysql is working - sql query i wrote which is working fine -

`select topic from problems_solved where Site in (select Site from problems_solved)`

But in grafana its not working. I am trying this query - `select topic from problems_solved where Site in(select ${Site} from problems_solved)`. I tried with other queries are well but its not working. Can somebody help me out here.

Thanks

Comment: `Site = ${Site}` expect only one value. What is the error in grafana for your working query ?

Comment: Yeah, that true. For grafana i am not getting any error only not seeing data. Can you wrote query for that. I am not able to figure out how to write query for this.

Comment: I am using only one table. Edited question as per as your comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use variable fomating, which creates correct SQL syntax (and more effective approach + remove duplicates). You can use [Grafana advanced variable format options](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/advanced-variable-format-options/). Example:

1.) `Site` variable:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Site 
FROM problems_solved
```

2.) `Topic` variable:

```
SELECT DISTINCT topic 
FROM problems_solved
WHERE Site IN (${Site:sqlstring})
```